# How to toggle an element from a parent div from within a child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle a parent div **.dropdown** that when clicked it reveals the child div **.dropdown-content** and in the child div is a back button **.fa-arrow-left** that hides the child div when clicked. My problem is when I try to click the parent div again the child div does not reappear. Anyone have a solution for this problem?

```js
const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-nav .dropdown");

for (var i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
  dropDowns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.children[1].classList.toggle("active");
  });
}

$('.fa-arrow-left').on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
    dropDowns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.children[1].classList.toggle("active", false);
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-nav" id="myMobileNav">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="sign-in">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
      <span>Sign-in</span>
    </div>
    {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %} {% assign child_list_handle = link.title | handle %} {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %} {% if linklists[child_list_handle] and linklists[child_list_handle].links.size > 0 %}
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">{{ link.title }}
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="mm-row">
          <div class="mm-column">
            <div class="mm-subcategory">
              <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
              <h3>{{ link.title | link_to: link.url }}</h3>
            </div>
            {% for child_link in linklists[child_list_handle].links %} {{ child_link.title | link_to: child_link.url }} {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-feature">
            {% assign collection= collections.winter-wear %}
            <img src="{{ collection.image | img_url: '908x330' }}">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /dropdown-content -->
    </div>
    {% else %} {{ link.title | link_to: link.url }} {% endif %} {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <!-- /navbar -->
  <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-3x" onclick="closeNav()"></i>
</div>
<!-- /mobile-nav -->
```

Comment: I made a fiddle for your, edit it to make a  [mre] of your problem with same dummy data. You will have much higher chances of someone answering.

Comment: I'll probably have to recreate it from scratch and simplify it because this is something I'm trying in shopify at the moment.

Comment: I really recommend stopping to use indexed for-loops. Use forEach or for..of instead. Also I recmmoned **highly**  to stay away from jQuery.

Comment: user2305686 : Please do.  Also @connexo : Any particular strong reason for staying away from jQuery?

Comment: We're in 2020.jQuery is not as useful as it used to be, and for less experienced developers I'd argue it is even damaging because it creates wrong expectations as of how the native DOM API is working.